# Android - how to add gain control when recording

Tags: android, audio, fft, audio-recording, audiorecord

I work for an audio recorder app and would like to  add gain control but I don't know how to do it. I have access to audio buffer but I don't know how to make the sound louder or slower.
I see another apps that have a seekBar for selecting the decibels from a specific range.

```
aRecorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
fWriter.write(buffer); // Write buffer to file
```

Please tell me what should I do to implement gain control in my app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the volume is simple, just multiply all the samples by some fraction. A change of +/- 3dB (decibels) corresponds to multiplication by 2 or 0.5 respectively (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel). To prevent discontinuities in the output, make sure that you vary the multiplication factor smoothly from beginning to end.

See AudioSampleBuffer::applyGainRamp() @ http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/api/classAudioSampleBuffer.html

Comment: Thanks, I will try implementing what you suggested. Please tell me if there is some formula to get fraction from the decibels variation(eg: 3dB : 2 and (-3)dB : 0.5).

Comment: scale = std::pow (10, decibels / 20.0 )