# AudioRecord gain control getting noisy sound

Tags: java, android, audio, audio-recording, amplitude

I gone through stack overflow question [apply gain with variation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578865/android-audiorecord-apply-gain-with-variation?rq=1) same as what i want to know But couldnt find the answer i tried what ever the answeres they mentioned in above question link there is no proper or exact solution still i am getting voice (like Walkie-Talkie). Any one who done it properly.

```
 public class Mediarec extends Activity {

public static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 16000;

private AudioRecord mRecorder;
private File mRecording;
private short[] mBuffer;
private final String startRecordingLabel = "Start recording";
private final String stopRecordingLabel = "Stop recording";
private boolean mIsRecording = false;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
short iGain= (short)1.0f;
CheckBox gain;

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_mediarec);

    initRecorder();

    gain = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    button.setText(startRecordingLabel);

    gain.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

               if(gain.isChecked())
               {
                   
                   iGain = (short) Math.pow(10, 9.0 / 20.0 ) ;
                  // iGain = (short)2.0f;
               }
               else
               {
                   iGain = (short) Math.pow(10, 3 / 20.0 ) ;
               }
           }
        });
    
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            if (!mIsRecording) {
                button.setText(stopRecordingLabel);
                mIsRecording = true;
                mRecorder.startRecording();
                mRecording = getFile("raw");
                startBufferedWrite(mRecording);
            }
            else {
                button.setText(startRecordingLabel);
                mIsRecording = false;
                mRecorder.stop();
                File waveFile = getFile("wav");
                try {
                    rawToWave(mRecording, waveFile);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(Mediarec.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                Toast.makeText(Mediarec.this, "Recorded to " + waveFile.getName(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mRecorder.release();
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void initRecorder() {
    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    mBuffer = new short[bufferSize];
    mRecorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);
}

private void startBufferedWrite(final File file) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            DataOutputStream output = null;
            try {
                output = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)));
                while (mIsRecording) {
                    double sum = 0;
                    int readSize = mRecorder.read(mBuffer, 0, mBuffer.length);
                    for (int i = 0; i < readSize; i++) {
                        output.writeShort(mBuffer[i]);
                        sum += mBuffer[i] * mBuffer[i];
                    }
                    if (readSize > 0) {
                        final double amplitude = sum / readSize;
                        mProgressBar.setProgress((int) Math.sqrt(amplitude));
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(Mediarec.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } finally {
                mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                if (output != null) {
                    try {
                        output.flush();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(Mediarec.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            output.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(Mediarec.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

private void rawToWave(final File rawFile, final File waveFile) throws IOException {

    byte[] rawData = new byte[(int) rawFile.length()];
    DataInputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(rawFile));
        input.read(rawData);
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            input.close();
        }
    }

    DataOutputStream output = null;
    try {
        output = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(waveFile));
        // WAVE header
        // see http://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/
        writeString(output, "RIFF"); // chunk id
        writeInt(output, 36 + rawData.length); // chunk size
        writeString(output, "WAVE"); // format
        writeString(output, "fmt "); // subchunk 1 id
        writeInt(output, 16); // subchunk 1 size
        writeShort(output, (short) 1); // audio format (1 = PCM)
        writeShort(output, (short) 1); // number of channels
        writeInt(output, SAMPLE_RATE); // sample rate
        writeInt(output, SAMPLE_RATE * 2); // byte rate
        writeShort(output, (short) 2); // block align
        writeShort(output, (short) 16); // bits per sample
        writeString(output, "data"); // subchunk 2 id
        writeInt(output, rawData.length); // subchunk 2 size
        // Audio data (conversion big endian -> little endian)
        short[] shorts = new short[rawData.length / 2];
        ByteBuffer.wrap(rawData).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(shorts);
        ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(shorts.length * 2);
        
    
        for (short s : shorts) {
            
            //Apply Gain
            s *= iGain;
            
                             if(s>32767)
            {
                s=32767;
            }
            else if(s<-32768)
            {
                s=-32768;
            }
            bytes.putShort(s);
        }
        output.write(bytes.array());
    } finally {
        if (output != null) {
            output.close();
        }
    }
}

private File getFile(final String suffix) {
    Time time = new Time();
    time.setToNow();
    return new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), time.format("%Y%m%d%H%M%S") + "." + suffix);
}

private void writeInt(final DataOutputStream output, final int value) throws IOException {
    output.write(value >> 0);
    output.write(value >> 8);
    output.write(value >> 16);
    output.write(value >> 24);
}

private void writeShort(final DataOutputStream output, final short value) throws IOException {
    output.write(value >> 0);
    output.write(value >> 8);
}

private void writeString(final DataOutputStream output, final String value) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
        output.write(value.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

}

Voice is Very Low
Looking For solution how to apply gain with variation