# Can I set volume beyond AudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume?

Tags: android, max, volume

I am making a birding app with playback to call birds. Many of the songs recorded are quite bad, some with very low volume. I know how to set max volume of music with

```
 AudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 
        mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);
```

but this may not be enough for many songs; my Galaxy Note has quite bad speakers, and even with headphones max is low...

Would it be possible to add gain over this max for low volume songs, in order to be played at a decent volume?

This may sound like a silly question, but mplayer for Linux/Maemo has this option, called *gain*, that allowed me to play some songs higher than max in a Nokia N800.

Thanks!!

Comment: IMHO, you should modify the volume of your audio samples off-line before including them in your app.

Comment: @EdwardFalk: These are between 10 and 50 songs for each of 1832 bird species, 7GB of small song files, that I update periodically... :)

Comment: I'm sure there must be utilities out there that will read a .wav file, normalize their volume, and write them back out again.

Comment: @EdwardFalk: No doubt. But how long that would take over 50000 files in 7GB?

Comment: Off line on a reasonably modern PC?  Maybe an hour or two.  How often do you need to do it?

Comment: I would be surprised if it is so fast, but maybe your're right. I have to do this once a month, maybe. Other problem is that some of the songs are ok, so the gain should be applied selectively. So I would need to analyze each song before applying corrections.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using mediaplayer use audiotrack to play the filese. for the the work flow will be following

1. read from the files as byte or short array
2. to add a gain just multiply the sample by some fraction 
   (related question [Android - how to add gain control when recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449963/android-how-to-add-gain-control-when-recording))
3. now write the samples to audiotrack
4. then play it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I understood. You mean to process the audio file before playing it?  That should have strong impact on battery, speed, etc... Thanks!

Comment: It will have some impact, but not much worse than letting the system process the audio in the media player, which it will have to do one way or another.